# Performance:-How to reduce precompiled js file size in angularjs and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, nginx

I am working on a website which is based on angularjs and rails in the backend.

The site is currently in production/live

The issue which I am having is that after the assets have been precompiled with the help of `rake assets:precompile`,The overall js file size goes above 1Mb.Hence it takes time for the site to load.

This is a major issue and since the site is fully ajax based,I cannot implement page caching.

Also have tried gzip on my nginx server but this is not helping.

This is hampering the performance of the site and would welcome any sort of help or suggestions if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about RoR or the rake assets you mentioned but here is a few leads and how I proceed (Lately, I've been starting to use Grunt) :

1. Concat your js files into 1 js file. It's easier to process one request rather than many little ones.
2. Minify your js files and make sure to use minified lib version.
3. Try to adopt a smart approach to load your libraries and your own files. For instance, if you only need graphics in your admin dashboard, make sure not to load d3.js on your front page. I know the Jquery ecosystem is full of useful plugins but I've seen way too many developers taking shortcuts and claiming they need Jquery when others viable alternatives exist.
4. Serving file using gzip is a good idea. This should reduces the size of your files significantly.

Also, Could you provide a link to your website ?

Comment: ..Thanks for the reply.Rake precompile converts all the js files into a single js file as mentioned above..
Also the link to the website is whatsonarabia.com..You can visit it.Would be helpful if you get any other suggestions.Thanks a lot

Comment: The website made my browser froze at the initial loading. The size of js files is not the only issue. In your javascript code make sure that you don't $watch too many elements, use the Batarang chrome plugin to profile your performances and watch out for bottlenecks. Consider using sprites for your images

Comment: @alexandre-nucera...Thanks for checking the website..Will check out.Am actually working on the maintenance of the code hence it takes me time to understand the code.Also the project is massive so have to be careful as one change can affect the whole project